# Python dictionary from excel

Tags: python, excel, dictionary

I need to create a dictionary from an excel file. This looks like this:

```
Key   Value
aa    A
ab    A
ac    A
ad    B
ae    B
af    B
ag    B
ah    B
```

The outcome would be a dictionary looking like:

```
dictionary ={'aa': 'A', 'ab': 'A', 'ac': 'A', 'ad': 'B', 'ae': 'B', 'af': 'B', 'ag': 'B', 'ah': 'B' }
```

Comment: That does look like that! Have at look here though :0) http://www.python-excel.org/

Comment: save as a csv and use the `csv` module with `csv.DictReader()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

quick example:

```
import csv

dictionary = {}
with open('data.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    for row in reader:
        dictionary[row['Key']] = row['Value']
```

Comment: The output of your example is

`{'ad': 'B', 'ag': 'B', 'ae': 'B', 'ab': 'A', 'af': 'B', 'ah': 'B', 'ac': 'A', 'aa': 'A'}`

So you're good.

Comment: thx, I just threw it together quick... whenever I see an excel question, it can usually be solved with the stdlib csv module.

Comment: Nice to know. I haven't done much work with excel, but I'm sure I will in the future so this will be useful.